# error with rvest html_table

Tags: r, error-handling, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to scrape single table off of a list of 220 simple web sites. Each site has a single table on it that I want to scrape and put into a character vector, then rbind all 220 character vectors into a single data frame.

Check if web pages exist, 200 = ok, 404 = page not found.

```
UrlListCheck <- unlist ( lapply(lapply(url_list, html_session), function(x) {
    lapply(x$response$status_code, identity)
    } ))
```

all 220 pages are ok.

check url format to download each html_table as character vector

```
215 -> x ; html_table(html_session(url_list[[x]]))[[1]][,2]

[1] ""                 "field2"         ""                
[4] "field4" ""                 "field6"    
[7] "field7"
```

The above works fine for all of the urls I check manually.

The html_session works fine with lapply over the url list.

```
test1 <- lapply(url_list, html_session)
```

But the html_table function throws an error with lapply over the list.

```
test2 <- lapply(test1, html_table)

Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = p): 
invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
```

Any suggestions?

Output from the code below is what I want ultimately, which has worked for me on numerous other web pages with the same format on the same server.

```
TablesList <- lapply(url_list, function(x) {
                            html_table(html_session(x))[[1]][,2] } )
```

Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = p): 
    invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)*

```
ResultDF <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, TablesList))
```